# how to get the value of width shown in html tag using selenium and python

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

I want to get the width % shown. So  that i can monitor the progress.How to get the value using selenium in python.

I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried any code? Done any effort?

Comment: html: <div id="progress-complete0" class="progress-complete">
            <div id="progress-image0" class="progress-image" style="width: 100%; background-image: url(https://xyz;">&nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: share code with question.

Comment: I think it would help to add some more detail about what you're working with. Are you trying to get the width of a progress bar? Do you have access to the underlying data, etc.

Comment: actually its an upload progress bar. i want the width value so that i can monitor if upload is complete

Comment: never worked on python but can you use `print driver.find_element_by_class_name("progress-image").get_attribute("style").split(';')[0].split()[1]` if i am getting you right that you require width in style.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your class **"progress-image"** is unique and used only once for mentioned div as per your shared html code in comment.

Following will get width of mentioned class div :

```
    element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("progress-image")

    size = element.size
    print(size)
```

Comment: is it possible to find using python

Comment: Yes see I have update code as per python syntax in my answer.

Comment: tried this                                                                                                            e = driver.find_element_by_class_name("progress-image").get_attribute("width")                                                                                 print e                                                                                                                                 but getting value as none

Comment: got error:                                                                                             AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getCssValue'

Comment: I think get css value not supporting in python.

Comment: accoring to progress value doesnt change.

Comment: Can you try out with the code i provided in ques comment?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_class_name("progress-image").get_attribute("style").split(';')[0].split()[1]
                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: can u tell o/p of `driver.find_element_by_class_name("progress-image").get_attribute("style")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `size` call in the Webelement of Webdriver.

**size** Returns the size of the element

Example:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
e = driver.find_element_by_class_name("progress-image")
size = e.size
print(size)
```

From documentation http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement

Answer (score 0):

You can **fetch the attribute style's value using [get_attribute method](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/selenium/selenium.selenium.html?highlight=get_attribute#selenium.selenium.selenium.get_attribute) and then use [split method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) to split the resultant string and get the width value as @Vivek has suggested.**

Also, since this is a progress-bar, as you say, then try waiting for its visibility first, using [explicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) and then fetch the attribute, as below:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'progress-image')))

element_width = element.get_attribute('style').split(';')[0].split(':')[1]
print(element_width)
```

**NOTE:** The above code waits for 20 seconds till the visibility of the progress-bar element is located. Then, it fetches the style attribute of the progress-bar element and then splits it to fetch the required width value.

Furthermore, as mentioned in [get_attribute method](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/selenium/selenium.selenium.html?highlight=get_attribute#selenium.selenium.selenium.get_attribute),

```
the value of the attribute so fetched may differ across browsers 
(this is the case for the “style” attribute, for example)
```

### EDIT

To wait till the upload is complete:

```
//waiting 3 minutes till the upload the uploader status has the title 'Click to close.'
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 180)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='uploader-status' and contains(@title, 'close')]")))
```

Comment: getting error  :                                                                                       element_width = element.get_attribute('style').split(';',1)[0].split(':')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Amritha: Have modified my code.. Can you please check and let me know, if it works.?

Comment: got error:                                                                                                            File "upload.py", line 80, in test_upload
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,'progress-image')))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message)
TimeoutException: Message: ''

Comment: @Amritha: Oh! my bad.. I should've waited for the visibility.. Have changed my code. Please check now..

Comment: while uploading code is   <div id="uploaderstatus3" class="uploader-status" valign="middle" style="display: block;">                                                                                                  after upload is complete code is shown as                                                                                       <div id="uploaderstatus3" class="uploader-status complete" valign="middle" style="display: block;" title="Click to close.">                            please help me wait driver until class is shown as uploader-status complete or title is Click to close.

Comment: Check the code under **Edit** , in my answer above, and see if it works out for you.

Comment: While executing your code, does the upload status for 'Upload complete' appear on your screen ?

Comment: xyz.zip: 28.16 MB complete......status visible after completion and while uploading % is shown.but file name will change each time.

Comment: Okay.. Since, I had given the maximum the code can wait, is 3 minutes.. So, did your upload finish within 3 minutes or did it take more than that ?

Comment: Okay.. I have modified my code under **Edit** in my answer above. Please try that and let me know

Comment: Forgive me, but I am out of ideas, really. Do the steps MANUALLY (don't execute your code, just go through it manually) in Firefox browser, and when the file gets uploaded and the upload status is shown, open the [Firepath add-on panel of firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/), and use the xpath I've added above. Let me know, if the **uploader element** gets highlighted or not.

Comment: thanks for all the help.......got solution                                                               hidden_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@title, 'Click to close.')]")
        while hidden_element.is_displayed():
         if hidden_element.is_displayed():
           print "Element found"
           break
         else:
           print "Element not found"
           sleep(2)

Comment: Okay Great... Cheers.. :) Only thing that might be a problem in your code, is the while loop.. Just in case,**the "Upload" gets any error and the Upload bar doesn't show up, your while loop will go into an infinite one..** So, try to execute that code for some timelimit.

Comment: ya sure will do that.